# Existance of 3 words in a string in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check whether 3 specific words exists in a column or not using an Oracle query.

For example my column value is: 
`'Google Earth lets you fly anywhere on Earth to view satellite imagery, maps, terrain, 3D buildings, from galaxies in outer space to the canyons of the ocean'`.

I want to check whether the three words `Earth`, `galaxies` and `buildings` exist in the string.

How I can do this in an Oracle query?

Comment: Are you looking for words or strings?  Does "unearth" or "Earthling" count?

Comment: only exact words. "unearth" should not count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look for words only probably. So when looking for `'space'` you don't want to find, say, `'respaced'`. Use `REGEXP_LIKE` with word boundaries:

```
select *
from mytable 
where regexp_like(text, '(^|\W)earth(\W|$)', 'i')
  and regexp_like(text, '(^|\W)galaxies(\W|$)', 'i')
  and regexp_like(text, '(^|\W)buildings(\W|$)', 'i');
```

Comment: For efficiency, it is always best to put the more likely match first in an alternation: `(\W|^)` rather than the other way around (although in this case it will likely make little difference). Other that that, this should be the winner.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this in the where clause (if you want to be exact about the case):

```
where col_name like '%Earth%' 
and col_name like '%galaxies%' 
and col_name like '%buildings%'
```

as @Tim pointed out in the comments, if you want to ignore case, you can by using upper() or lower():

```
where upper(col_name) like '%EARTH%'
and upper(col_name) like '%GALAXIES%'
```

etc.

Comment: Use `UPPER(col_name) LIKE '%EARTH%'` to handle possible case sensitivity issues.

Comment: Beware of the "mother is in chemotherapy" problem. It is called that because the word "mother", for which you are presumably searching, is also found within the word "che**mother**apy".

Comment: @mathguy is right - this will return sub words.  I upvoted Throsten's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp:

```
WITH tmp AS
  (
    SELECT 'Earth, galaxies and buildings' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Earth, buildings and galaxies' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Earth2, galaxies and buildings' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Earth , galaxies and buildings' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Earth,galaxies,buildings' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Earthgalaxiesbuildings' str FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'earth, galaxies and buildings' str FROM dual
  )
SELECT
  str
FROM
  tmp
WHERE
  REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(str), '([[:punct:][:space:]]|^)EARTH([[:punct:][:space:]]|$)') AND
  REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(str), '([[:punct:][:space:]]|^)GALAXIES([[:punct:][:space:]]|$)') AND
  REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(str), '([[:punct:][:space:]]|^)BUILDINGS([[:punct:][:space:]]|$)')
```

Comment: This is the right approach. With that said: for efficiency, in any alternation group (like your first group, searching either for the beginning of the string or for something else), it is best for efficiency to put the most common match first; put the `^` last, since it will be matched less often. Also: did you intentionally make `'Earth,galaxies,buildings'` (with no spaces) be a **non**-match?

Answer (score 0):

"Earth" "Earth," should be selected as word as per logic. Using '%Earth% will also become true for words like "Un-Earth" or "Earthing" and you don't want it.

So,

```
where (upper(col) like upper('% earth %') OR upper(col) like upper('% earth.%') OR upper(col) like upper('% earth,%') ) AND
  (upper(col) like upper('% galaxies %') OR upper(col) like upper('% galaxies.%') OR upper(col) like upper('% galaxies,%')) AND
  upper(col) like upper('% buildings %') OR upper(col) like upper('% buildings.%') OR upper(col) like upper('% buildings,%'))
```

based on how much data is corrupt, you can add multiple condition inside OR.